# Configuring test files in a jhipster project: Best practices and solutions

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have built a **jhipster** Spring boot React **Maven** project and want to build the project with related **Testers** via this command: ./mvnw -Pprod clean verify.
How could I configure test files to run without any error?
I mean how to modify pom.xml, dependencies and any other related files

When I tried, is shows these kind of errors:

> HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeInstantWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnGMTTimeZone
> » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: Can you please provide the JDL you used to create your project? That way, we can try to reproduce the problem and see if it's a bug in JHipster.

Comment: Please post full stack error as we can't the exception root cause here.